# How to check UITableViewCell fully visible / loaded with Swift - iOS (setSelected)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

I have UITableView with CustomCell. I want to rotate record image when a cell fully visible or visible more than half at least.

This code block in CustomTableViewCell.swift

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    RotateImage()
}
```

The problem is that image is starting rotate immediately custom cell appeared like image below.

Sample Image:

- There are 2 cells. First one is fully visible and rotating. And second one is partially visible / loaded but its also rotating.

### [image: records]

Is it possible to check visibility in setSelected code block or need to check with UITableView functions?

The result should be like that:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if fullyVisible == true
    {
      RotateImage()
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want more control for the behavior of cells based on their visibility withing the bounds of your screen, you could use UIScrollViewDelegate functions
such as:

```
 optional func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

Get an array of the tableView's visible cells.
you can check the bounds of each cell to see if it is on screen
Check if the cell's record is spinning and if not start the rotation.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar in one of my projects:

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let visibleArea = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.height
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
        guard let propertyGraphCell = cell as? PropertyGraphCell else { continue }
        if cell.frame.midY <= visibleArea, let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            switch visibleRows[indexPath.row] {
            case .daysOnMarket:
                if daysOnMarketAnimated {
                    propertyGraphCell.drawLine(animated: true)
                    daysOnMarketAnimated = false
                }
            case .priceTrend:
                if priceTrendAnimated {
                    propertyGraphCell.drawLine(animated: true)
                    priceTrendAnimated = false
                }
            case .vendorDiscount:
                if vendorDiscountAnimated {
                    propertyGraphCell.drawLine(animated: true)
                    vendorDiscountAnimated = false
                }
            case .marketInsights:
                assert(false, "cell animation not supported")
            }
        }
    }
}
```